# Does Access have any issues with unicode capable data types like nvarchar in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, unicode, nvarchar

I am using Access 2003 as a front end UI for a SQL Server 2008 database. In looking at my SQL Server database design I am wondering if nvarchar was the right choice to use over varchar. I chose nvarchar because I thought it would be useful in case any characters represented by unicode needed to be entered. However, I didn't think about any possible issues with Access 2003 using the uni-code datatype. Are there any issues with Access 2003 working with unicode datatypes within SQL Server (i.e. nvarchar)? Thank you.

Comment: I've used Access as a front end to SQL server 2005 (not 2008) and pretty much use nvarchar exclusively, with no problems. Of course, I might not be doing the same things as you so ymmv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go ahead and use `nvarchar`, if that's the correct datatype for the job. Access supports Unicode data, both with it's own tables and with external (linked) tables and direct queries.

Comment: +1 Access 2000 and later use Unicode for text, memo, and hyperlink fields.  And when upsizing a Jet table to SQL Server, the Upsizing Wizard creates an nvarchar field for a Jet text field.  nvarchar as "correct datatype for the job" seems right to me.