# After altering column in SQL Server, Access linked tables will not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ddl, linked-tables

After running this SQL script in SQL Server 2012:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 
   ALTER COLUMN name NVARCHAR(50)
```

I am unable to create a linked table from Access 2013.

The following error is displayed when I attempt to link to the SQL Server table:

[image]

Comment: What was the data type before? This should work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064047/does-access-have-any-issues-with-unicode-capable-data-types-like-nvarchar-in-sql -- `name` is a bad choice for column name, since it's a reserved word, but should not cause this error as well.

Comment: The data type before was NVARCHAR(20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this case ended up being a spatial index.  Access would not add the linked table if the spatial index existed.  I simply removed the spatial index temporarily, added the linked table in access and then recreated the spatial index on my sql column.